# org.antlr.v4.runtime.misc.TestRig hangs

Tags: windows, antlr, java

I am trying to execute ANTLRv4 example from here http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR4/Getting+Started+with+ANTLR+v4.

I have downloaded `antlr-4.0-complete.jar` and placed it into some directory.

I have created `bat` files to run `org.antlr.v4.Tool` (antlr.bat) and `org.antlr.v4.runtime.misc.TestRig` (run.bat).

Tool runs without parameters and outputs something, so paths are ok.

I have created `Hello.g4` with the following content:

```
// Define a grammar called Hello
grammar Hello;
r  : 'hello' ID ;         // match keyword hello followed by an identifier
ID : [a-z]+ ;             // match lower-case identifiers
WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ; // skip spaces, tabs, newlines
```

EVERYTHING IN THE SAME DIRECTORY except `antlr-4.0-complete.jar`

Then I run `antlr4 Hello.g4` and getting no errors. Some files appear in current directory (`*.java` and `*.tokens`). No `Hello.java` file appears.

Then I run `javac Hello*.java` to compile. Some `*.class` files appear.

Then I run `run Hello r -tree` and it hangs with no error message.

OS is Window 8 x64

Java is 1.6 32 bit

How to run ANTLR example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oh, it was waiting for my input from console! It is not very clear in sample.

Comment: Hi there, I appreciate that it's been several months since you did this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16385451/org-antlr-v4-runtime-misc-testrig-hangs

But when you say it's waiting for input?  I seem to have hit the same problem, but I'm typing the input in the example:

hello parrt
^D
(r hello parrt)

And it's still just sitting there waiting for something, I've also tried replacing the ^D with ^Z.  Can you remember what you did?  Is it waiting for a specific code or something?

Comment: If you run it with  `java org.antlr.v4.runtime.misc.TestRig Hello r -tree` then you should type something, like "hello world", then press `ENTER`, then press `Ctrl-Z`, then pres `ENTER` again. It will respond with `(r hello world)` which is grammatical interpretation of entered phrase.

Comment: Also you can run it with `java org.antlr.v4.runtime.misc.TestRig Hello r -gui` then enter the same I wrote above and it will respond by drawing grammatical structure in the window.

Comment: I found this answer thinking it was hanged at first too, though later I ran into another problem: the Ctrl+Z might not be working under Windows on Cygwin. If it prints messages such as `0 [sig] bash 963! sigpacket::process: Suppressing signal 18 to win32 process (pid 18484)`, it is probably the case. I recommend to try invoking TestRig with file rather than console input. File input works well on both platforms. (Console input works well on native Windows cmd too, thanks.)